# Xcode 7 [Objective-c] Methods Conflicting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I run my application it adds the score but doesn't change where the block is placed after I tap it.

```
- (IBAction)Block:(id)sender{

Random = arc4random() %219;
Random = Random + 61;

BlockI.center = CGPointMake(0, Random);
BlockB.center = CGPointMake(0, Random);

[self Score];

}

- (void)Score{

ScoreInt = ScoreInt + 1;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)ScoreInt];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ScoreInt forKey:@"ScoreSaved"];

}
```

Now if I delete the part:

```
[self Score];
```

and

```
 - (void)Score{

ScoreInt = ScoreInt + 1;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)ScoreInt];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ScoreInt forKey:@"ScoreSaved"];
}
```

Then I get the random placement of the block but the score doesn't increase when I tap it.

-Thanks,
Derek

Comment: scoreint have values ?

Comment: scrore.text whats getting printed

Comment: @KishoreKumar Yes in the [viewDidLoad] I put "ScoreInt = 0;"

Comment: try like this scoreint++;

Comment: @KishoreKumar Nope. It Adds score but the block goes back to x: 0, and its set y position(in the storyboard).

Comment: Can you attach the full code? How many blocks are there. From the code it seems that there are 2 blocks I and B. And they are being placed on the same center. So one will come over the other. Is that correct behaviour?

Comment: Yes @Pradeep K I put the Button with the Image underneath and the button on top just to see if it would work but sadly it didn't

Answer (score 1):

You have not `synchronize` the `NSUserDefaults` so  `synchronize` the `NSUserDefaults`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

To stored your value in NSUserDefaults, so you have must be synchronize the NSUserDefaults. If not synchronize a NSUserDefaults, not stroed your set values. To write the Code...

```
- (void)Score
{
   ScoreInt = ScoreInt + 1;
   Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)ScoreInt];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ScoreInt forKey:@"ScoreSaved"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Im not trying to save my integer i need to add to my integer and place the block in the random y positions at once

Comment: `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` use for stoed value in cache memory in your app developing requeriment